# WCF Data Service : Performance issue while fetching nested entities

Tags: performance, wcf-data-services

My Database Schema :

```
table : Terminology (ID (PK), Name, Comments)
table : Content (ID (PK), TerminologyID (FK), Data, LangaugeID)
```

1 - many relationship between Terminology and Content. One Terminology can have any number of content based on different language ID.

Terminology and Contents table may have millions of records.

Now, even thought I fetch some hundreds of record (pagination) from my client side using WCF data Service, after 5-6 attempts, I get time out exception.

```
_DataService.Terminologies.Expand("Contents").Skip(index1).Take(count).ToList();
```

If I don't expand my Contents, query works fine :), but I will not have Content Data.
What is the best way to handle this scenario.

Options...

1. Is there any performance improvement, if I use Include in ServerSide (I mean, writing Custom webget method) over Exapnd in Client Side.
2. Creating database Views and accessing it over client side.
3. Creating Stored Procedure, where I can pass my preferred LanguageID and call it from client side.

Comment: As with any perfomance problem - measure it. See where the problem is. Is it slow on the client or on the server. If it's on the server - where? What SQL is it running against the DB and what is the query plan? It's likely that the query is for some reason not using index and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Is this ADO.NET DataServices build by default wizard?

In any case if your client can access database directly, it will be a lot faster, so if direct db option is available then take it.

If WCF is the only option, then you will have to create your own implementation of Paging Web Service, perhaps even with store procedure that returns multiple recordsets.

On a side note I do not see LanguageId in your service query, and that could slow things down a lot.

```
_DataService.Terminologies.Expand("Contents").Skip(index1).Take(count).ToList();
```